# handle QueryList changes initially

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using a QueryList

```
  @ViewChildren(SortableTableColDirective)
  sortableHeaders!: QueryList<SortableTableColDirective>;
```

The directive has a Subject which will be emitted when the sorting order of the particular column has changed.

```
  ...
  private _sort$ = new Subject<SortEvent>();

  get sort$(): Observable<SortEvent> {
    return this._sort$.asObservable();
  }

  private emit(): void {
    this._sort$.next({ column: this.appSortableTableCol, direction: this.direction });
  }
  ...
```

I don't want to use @Output here, because then I would have to write the output-binding on every single table header column. Instead of that, I want to handle all directives on a central place.

So this was my first attempt in the Component itself:

```
merge(...this.sortableHeaders.map(f => f.sort$))
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  )
  .subscribe(event => {
    this.sort(event);
  });
```

This works great, but with this implementation dynamic added/removed sortableHeaders won't be processed in the merge observable, because this will only be created once.

So I thought it would be better to listen to the QueryList changes.

```
this.sortableHeaders.changes.pipe(
  switchMap(() => ...this.sortableHeaders.map(f => f.sort$)),
  takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
).subscribe(event => {
  this.sort(event);
});
```

But that will only work after the QueryList has changed, NOT for the first time.

How can I archive that the inner switchMap will be triggered initially?

Should I use "merge" with a dummy observable like the following?

```
merge(of(undefined), this.sortableHeaders.changes).pipe(
  switchMap(() => ...this.sortableHeaders.map(f => f.sort$)),
  takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
).subscribe(event => {
  this.sort(event);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this line `switchMap(() => ...this.sortableHeaders.map(f => f.sort$)),` probably isn't doing what you want it to do. You're returning an array from `switchMap` projection function so `switchMap` will just iterate it and return each item of the array as is. This is because an array is so-called "observable like" object. In other words, `switchMap` will never subscribe to any of the `sort$` Observables because you're returning them basically as `[sort$, sort$, sort$, ...]`.

Instead you'll need to wrap it with another Observable that will subscribe to all of them:

```
switchMap(() => merge(...this.sortableHeaders.map(f => f.sort$))),
```

Then to your question, you don't need to merge `of(undefined)`. You can use for example `startWith(void 0))` to trigger the first change. The `void 0` is used only to make it obvious that the value doesn't matter so you could use `null` or `undefined` as well.

```
this.sortableHeaders.changes.pipe(
  startWith(void 0),
  switchMap(() => merge(...this.sortableHeaders.map(f => f.sort$))),
  takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
).subscribe(event => {
  this.sort(event);
});
```

Comment: Indeed, the first note was only written incorrectly in this stackoverflow question. I have the swtchMap(() => merge(...) in the real code. For the second note: Thank you very much. This is much more cleaner than my implementation